# Screen locks even when plugged in

Tags: windows-8, screensaver, laptop-display

I have attempted to prevent my screen from locking when plugged in for 3 hours, but it is not happening. These are my settings:

[image]

Nevertheless, if I leave my computer for 15 minutes it locks, even though it is plugged in. Is there some setting somewhere that is overriding these settings?

The screen locks after 10 minutes, just timed it.

Comment: While plugged in, does changing the "On battery" timeout to "1 minute" make the screen lock after 1 minute?

Comment: Please better explain "locking".  If it's stopping and asking you for a password, then it may just be a screen saver, check your display settings.

Comment: @Steven No, that has no effect. The screen locks after 10 minutes exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is happening because of a "screen saver" setting:

[image]

This is located in the "Personalize" part of the system options.

If you are on a domain, then network policies can be used to force the screen saver to be active. To see if this happening use the following command:

```
gpresult /Scope User /v > "c:/policies_output.txt"
```

Then examine the output file.

Comment: This is wrong.  If no screensaver is set then it should not be affecting it, as the timeout listed there does nothing when no screen saver is set.  Did setting it to something else actually affect the timing of the problem you're encountering?

Comment: @'Techie007 If no screen saver is set, then the screen just goes black. This is indeed what is causing the lockout, a 10 minute screen saver setting. Try it on your own machine.

Comment: if no screensaver is set, then the screen blanking is not a Windows Screen saver kicking in and as well, the timer has no effect when no SS is set, since it's a screen saver-specific setting. :)  *Did setting it to something else actually affect the timing of the problem you're encountering?*  Or are you just assuming it's the cause because it says 10 minutes, and that's the timing you're seeing on your screen blanking?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I am pretty sure it is the screen saver. If I change the SS to "Bubbles" then in 10 minutes Bubbles comes on and I am locked out. If I change the SS to (None) then in 10 minutes the screen goes black and I am locked out.

Comment: You seem to be avoiding my question. :)  Have you confirmed that changing that SS timeout affects the timeframe for the screen blanking?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I can't change the screen saver timeout, it is grayed out.

Comment: Then you have not proved that this setting is what's causing/controlling the timeout you're seeing.  As you mentioned in your other question, you are on a domain.  ensure that there are no domain policies in place preventing you from changing this and/or hard setting the time-outs, and what happens at said time-out...